# (React) this.setState(current=>--current.number) works but this.setState(current=>current.number+1) won't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  state = {
    number:0
  };
  ADD = ()=>{
    this.setState(current=>current.number+1)
  };
  MINUS = ()=>{
    this.setState(current=>--current.number);
  };
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Number is: {this.state.number}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.ADD}>Add</button>
        <button onClick={this.MINUS}>Minus</button>
      </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Code above is class component that use in `ReactDOM.render(<App/>,docment.querySelector('#root'));`

`current=>--current.number` works well but **`current=>current.number-1`** doesn't work

I can't catch the difference between two

Also, I want to know what `setState` method dose when it takes `foo` as argument such `this.setState(foo)`

Comment: in your function version you aren't returning the new state, just the number.

Comment: So both returns just a number, but `--currrent.number` changes a number and returns it.... that's the difference right?

Comment: Neither one works properly. The state starts off as an *object* but you are then setting it to a *number*. Additionally try this in your browser console: `foo = (x)=>--x.current; bar = 3; console.log(foo(bar)); console.log(bar);` it doesn't do what you think it does...

Answer (score 0):

i've made a little changes and it works

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      number: 0
    };
  }

  ADD() {
    this.setState(prev =>({number: prev.number + 1}))
  }
  MINUS() {
    this.setState(prev =>({number: prev.number - 1}));
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
    <div >
      <h1> Number is: {
        this.state.number
      } 
      </h1> 
      <button onClick = {
        ()=>this.ADD()
      } > Add < /button> 
      <button onClick = {
        ()=>this.MINUS()
      } > Minus </button> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( 
<Counter/> ,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This still decrements `number` in the old state. `prev =>({number: --prev.number})` should be replaced with `prev => ({ number: prev.number - 1 })`

Comment: you're right Dustin .at that time i was writing the post i just wanted to show that i works both way. plus i thought predecrementation returns another new instance .but i saw that it mutates the value which we dont want.